# Allow only 1 symbol in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a custom control that allow users to enter either a decimal or in time format (hh:mm). So I would like that if the `TextBox` contain a period(.), the user will no longer add/enter a colon(:) and vice versa.

I have this code below so that user can only enter numeric, a period and a colon.

```
 private void txtTime_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) & !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) & !(Convert.ToString(e.KeyChar) == ".") & !(Convert.ToString(e.KeyChar) == ":")))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //only allow one '.' & ':'
            if (e.KeyChar == '.' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;                    
            }
            else if (e.KeyChar == ':' && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(':') > -1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So my question is, how will I do it?

Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is your question? Does your code work?

Comment: What if they **paste** into your control?...

Comment: Handle the `Validated` event, and check the textbox's contents.

Comment: @vasily.sib the question is how will I do that if the TextBox contains a period(.), the textbox should not allow the user to enter a colon(:) and vice versa.

Comment: Controls that try to prevent "invalid" input as the user types can be highly problematic for some users. It's usually a far better experience to validate on submission or at least to wait until focus is lost. Don't assume you know the users intentions better than they do as they type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For operators it is a nuisance if they have typed something, and they want to correct it, but they can't because there is an incorrect dot or a semicolon in it.

Suppose the operator tried to type `14:38:21`, but instead types:

14.38

"Oh no, this is wrong, I wanted 14.38:21! So let's first continue typing `:21` and then go back to change the dot into a colon!"

Imagine the operator's frustration when he can't type `:21`, and doesn't understand why

> In windows forms, only validate entered input when the operator expresses he finished editing the input.

Therefore, use `TextBox.OnValidating`. When this one is called, you can either accept or decline the input and tell the operator what is wrong.

```
protected override void OnValidating (CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = this.IsInputErrorDetected;
    if (e.Cancel)
    {
         this.DisplayInputProblem();
    }
}
```

Bonus point: also works with copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I will try using the validating event of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand your question good.
Maybe you are looking for `maskedTextBox` where you can specify mask of user input.

[image: maskedTextBox]

This one has mask for short time HH:MM

Comment: I know the maskedTextBox but I am looking for a control that allow the user to enter a Decimal value like 1.5 then on lost focus it will format to time like 1:30. So if the user enters 1:30 it will remain as 1:30.

Comment: @Zhyke - and what if the user types `1.30` assuming that'll be interpreted as 1 hour and 30 minutes (or 1 minute and 30 seconds) and doesn't notice your control "helpfully" reinterpreting their input? Best to have a *single* input format or to use a dedicated picker control..